When should a reference be given for a theorem when writing a PhD dissertation in pure mathematics?
The Question:
When should a reference be given for a theorem when writing a PhD dissertation in pure mathematics?
Context:
There's a grey area here, sure.  Let's focus on broad, guiding principles. Examples will help.
In this Mathematics Stack Exchange question, I asked for a reference for a well-known, simple theorem; the response I got was largely negative, with people saying such things do not need references in a PhD dissertation, especially when certain knowledge is assumed of the reader.  I'm not sure I agree, though I have gone with the compromise of saying in my dissertation,

[By] a well-known consequence of quadratic reciprocity, [the result].

This seems a legitimate practice.
But it got me thinking: when does a theorem need a reference in a pure mathematics dissertation?
Obviously, this is all with the understanding that authorship of the theorem is not claimed.

This seems a bit underspecified to me. When a theorem needs to be cited as a matter of academic ethics and when a theorem needs to be cited to get a good assessment of a dissertation are somewhat different questions.

Why don't you ask your advisor? He (or she) will surely know better what is appropriate for your thesis than some strangers on the internet who do not know what is common in your subarea of math.

People on the math stackexchange are mean and unfriendly in recent years. The culture there is to reflexively downvote and delete anything that looks simple or standard. I wouldn't take their response seriously for something like this.

I am confused why you use "pure mathematics" instead of "mathematics" here.

To state the obvious: What makes this a tough call is the tension between keeping the document well-referenced on the one hand, without on the other hand cluttering it up by referencing every background fact you use.
One useful and common technique for balancing these is to cite a few general background sources early in your document, typically in a “background” or “prerequisites” section/chapter, and take these as your benchmark for what you may use without giving a citation or recalling details (though of course sometimes you may still want to do so, when it suits the exposition).  Good such sources are typically reasonably up-to-date graduate-level textbooks or survey papers.  So for instance, you can write:

For general background on simplicial sets, we refer the reader to Goerss, Jardine (2009); for categorical semantics of type theory, see Hofmann (1997).

and if feeling particularly scrupulous, you might add:

Results from these will be used throughout without further comment.

and then you only need to cite/justify anything beyond these.  There may well still be some “well-known”/“easily-deducible” results not in these sources — but there shouldn’t be so many that citing/justifying them bogs down or clutters up your own work.  If there are still too many, try to add another background source covering as many as possible. And if you really can’t find such sources, that suggests your field is short of good up-to-date surveys, and that collecting and spelling out such details in your thesis is a useful service, not just clutter.

There is a point where a research result becomes part of the accepted canon of knowledge. At that point, you no longer need to provide a reference. For example, you will not have to provide a reference for the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra because it is covered in every text book and, in fact has its own Wikipedia page.
For theorems that have not (yet) achieved the status of canonical knowledge in a field, you need to provide a reference.

If you look at the issue that inspired this question - you will see that it is not canonical knowledge, but rather a fact that can easily be deduced from canonical knowledge - not a fact that is covered in textbooks, but a fact that is left as an exercise in some textbooks (and could be left as an exercise in many others).  It might be worth addressing this issue in your answer?

Good answer, but the part about the Wikipedia page seems irrelevant. There are many theorems that have Wikipedia pages but would still be sufficiently specialized to merit being referenced in a thesis.

Best practice here depends (duh) on context, to determine what is "common knowledge" (to whom?) and what needs citation.
Experts in a field will not need to be reminded of 200-year-old facts that they know very well.
And, even if the precise thing that you need is not exactly "quadratic reciprocity" (for example), experts will be well-acquainted with all the obvious exercises bases on that. :)

In case of doubt, give a reference to a textbook or add a short proof, maybe in an appendix.
This provides the additional benefit that your theorem is indeed correct, and you did not mix up any of the assumptions or definitions.

To some extend this is a matter of personal style or a university's group history. I now institutes that always cite the same papers when sketching some basics. Others do the same without giving the references or just referring to a well-established textbook to get the details there.
As a PhD student you might not be aware of this or have not yet developed your personal style. Discuss this with your advisor, (s)he is the authority regarding your PhD dissertation and should be happily guide you.
